# Treat object coming from server at app launch as non optional

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

When it launches, the first thing our app does is to load a user object from our backend, while showing a splash screen.
Once that user has been fetched, our home screen is shown and we can consider that this user is valid. However, this property can only be optional in our codebase since it doesn't have a default value, so swift forces us to either mark it as optional or implicitly unwrapped.

We don't want to make it implicitly unwrapped because then if future developper were to add code using the user object that is actually ran before the object is loaded from the server, the app would crash.

My question is then, is there a design pattern on iOS that would let swift understand something like: first run that small part of the codebase that loads the user, then consider the rest of the project can be ran knowing the object is valid ?

Answer (score 2):

> Once that user has been fetched, our home screen is shown and we can consider that this user is valid. However, this property can only be optional in our codebase since it doesn't have a default value, so swift forces us to either mark it as optional or implicitly unwrapped.

It can be non-optional if you programmatically create your home screen and add User to its `init`. (This fairly straightforward idea often goes by the IMO confusing name of "dependency injection" rather than the obvious name of "passing parameters.") This tends to spread through the whole system, requiring that most view controller be programmatically created. That does not mean you can't use Storyboards (or simpler XIBs), but it does typically mean you can't use segues and will need to handle navigation more programmatically to pass your properties through the system.

This approach lets you make strong requirements for the existence of various properties at each point that you need them. It is not all-or-nothing. You can have some screens that use optionals, some that use implicitly unwrapped optionals, and some that are programmatically created. It's even possible to evolve an existing system over to this a few pieces at a time.

---

To your last paragraph, there is a common technique of a `shared` instance that is implicitly unwrapped and gets assigned early in the program's life. You then have to promise not to call any of the "main" code before you initialize it. As you note, that means if it isn't called correctly, it will crash. Ultimately there is either a compile-time proof that a value *must* exist, or there is only a runtime assertions.

You prove that a value *must* exist by passing it. You implicitly assert the the object *should* exist by using `!`. If it's possible for a developer to call the code incorrectly, then it's not a proof.

Comment: Upvoted for the critique of "dependency injection" terminology. :)

Comment: Yeah that's our second option and I quite like it. Though it means passing that object to a high number of inits to make sure it always goes from our splash screen to the most remote part of our code base. It feels cleaner than all the unwripping, but not much more efficient in terms of "useless" lines of code written.

Comment: An idea that I had, but I couldn't find a good place to start with it, would be to have a "launcher" module that would be a super small and isolated part of our codebase just made to fetch the user. Then that module could initiatalise the main module with the retrieved user. I don't know if it's actually feasible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "initialize the main module" here. If you want the compiler to enforce the value's existence, then the value has to be passed. If you don't want the compiler to enforce the value's existence, then you will have the possibility of the value being missing at runtime (either via `?` or via `!`, depending on how you want to handle it). For example, you can have a global sharedInstance for User that gets initialized at runtime and then all the rest of the code assumes exists, but then if it doesn't exist, you will have to crash.

Comment: Ultimately the compiler can't prove it must exist if you don't force it to exist (by passing it as a value). If the compiler can't prove it *must* exist, then there will always be a runtime possibility that it doesn't. (Do note that it is somewhat common to bundle all the must-exist objects into something like Context or DataSource or Engine or even User. So typically you don't have to pass a bunch of individual parameters; everything just winds up accepting a "Context" bundle.

Comment: What I had in mind was something like this:
https://medium.com/captain-ios-experts/theawesomeapp-develop-multi-module-ios-app-with-ease-7a8b01366812

By having multiple modules in the app, I figured maybe I could have one that's the main one, loads the user and then creates the subsequent one with the valid user. It doesn't really seem to work that way though.

Comment: No, it can't work that way in Swift. You'd need a way to prove that the module cannot be created without the object, and a way for all controllers in the module to get their data only from their module. You can't do that with frameworks (dynamic or static, runtime loaded, or launch-time loaded). Languages like Scala can sort of fake it in syntax with implicit parameters, but they're still passing values to functions. Eventually you have to pass a value to a function to prove it exists.

Answer (score 1):

The correct design pattern is exactly what you are doing. When you have a data that won't be present at initialization time, make the property that holds it an Optional. `nil` means the data is not yet present; non-`nil` means that it is. This is completely standard stuff. Just keep doing it the way you are doing it.

If what bothers you is the fact that you have to fetch this thing as an Optional in every method that deals with it, well, tough. But at least the Swift language has nice techniques for safe unwrapping. Typically the first thing you will do in your method is to unwrap safely:

```
func f() {
    guard let myData = self.myData else { return }
    // and now myData is not Optional
}
```

The only I thing I would advise against here is the splash screen. What if the data *never* arrives? You need to show the user something real, perhaps with actual words saying "please wait while we fetch the data". You need to plan for possible timeout. So, what I'm saying is, your proposed *interface* might need some work. But your underlying technique of using an Optional is exactly right.

Comment: Yeah I understand that's probably the cleanest / most straight forward way to do it, but I was wondering if there was a way to somehow turn it into a non optional after we fetch the object since 99% of our code is actually dealing with a non optional version of it.

Comment: No, you can't magically turn an Optional into a non-Optional. And as you rightly say, an implicitly unwrapped Optional is skanky and dangerous. However, do note that your _code_ does not have to treat this thing as an Optional. Every method that fetches this value just needs a `guard let` statement at the start that unwraps the Optional, and so the whole rest of the method has a non-Optional to deal with. It's clean, it's pretty. No problem.

Comment: Yeah that issue with the rather boring splash screen is know by our product owners and we'll work on it, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Yeah we use guard let quite often for that, but as you can imagine this user object is core to the code base and pretty much everywhere, so we have a lot of guard lets because of that. It feels a bit frustrating.

Comment: Well, of course I see what you're saying, but basically to me it comes down to a question of the _flow_ of the app. If you don't have the data, you don't flow to the part of the app that needs the data. If you do have the data, you do flow there, and you are confident that you have the data because if you didn't, you wouldn't be here.